# Why did using Thin instead of WEBRick fix my JSON API woes (iOS)?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, afnetworking, thin

**Things are working, and I don't know why. This scares me.**

I recently asked another [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715912/unable-to-get-responses-from-local-server-when-connecting-via-ios-device) that had me confused for many hours. You can read the long description of the problem there, but I'll describe the gist of it:

I have a simple iOS project that asks for JSON data from a simple rails server. The requests work fine if I am running the project from the simulator, but kept failing when I ran it from my device.

I quickly discovered my first problem, using localhost as the base url for my AFNetworking client, and started using my IP address instead which allowed me to communicate with the server.

When making my GET requests, I could see that the request was hitting the server (by watching my terminal window) and that the server was returning a 200 response which should include the JSON representation of the items requested. However *the AFNetworking -getPath:parameters:success:failure method was failing every time.* I could inspect the response and see that it was of type 200, and if I simulated a failed request (such as 422) with a JSON error, I could see the error messages.

A [response to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17728531/827441) said that the JSON returned may not be valid which could be causing the request to fail.

Now the weird part:

I stumbled around for hours and found [a project](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/41-authentication-with-afnetworking) that used a rails server to retrieve a JSON response using AFNetworking. I compared it to my project and the two are essentially the same when it comes to AFNetworking. I then inspected the rails server. Here is the kicker: the only difference I could find was the use of the 'Thin' gem. I installed the gem and now my requests are completing successfully and I am getting back the JSON data.

Can anyone provide any insight as to why using Thin rather than WEBrick for my Rails server cause JSON data to be passed back to my device successfully?